# Display error message if data is null for jstree.core.data

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a jstree building nodes from a return data call. However sometimes it returns null and I need to handle this by showing some error message on the UI. I tried to add check on the returned data but it keeps showing loading icon and not display my intended div with the message. My code:

```
$('#jstree-test').jstree({
    core: {
        data: function (node, cb) {
            $.getJSON()
                .done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                if(data == null) 
                {                       
                    $('#Error').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    globfunc.redirect(xhr);
                    cb.call(this, data);    
                    }   

                })
                .fail(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    if (xhr.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
                        globfunc.redirect(xhr);
                    } else {
                        globfunc.showModal(xhr);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
})
```

Is there anything I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the strategy slightly. It could be one way of doing it, can be tried.

Call you ajax function first to get the data.
Then if there is data that is not null, initialise jsTree,

Otherwise handle the scenario as you wanted.

Something like below. Below code is not tested, it is just indicative. For details on this approach you can refer https://everyething.com/Example-of-simple-jsTree-with-dynamic-JSON-data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON()
                .done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                if(data == null) 
                {                       
                    $('#Error').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    globfunc.redirect(xhr);
                    createJSTree(data);    
                    }   

                })
                .fail(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    if (xhr.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
                        globfunc.redirect(xhr);
                    } else {
                        globfunc.showModal(xhr);
                    }
                });
        });

        function createJSTree(data) {            
            $('##jstree-test').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': data
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```